# Monaco Editor custom formatters

Tags: monaco-editor

I am trying to use the Monaco Editor by Microsoft in a project I am currently developing.  I have looked through the documentation and see that you can setup a custom language with custom code completion and syntax highlighting, but I cannot find any information on how we can add custom formatting to the custom language as well.

Is this a possibility?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read the docs: [registerDocumentFormattingEditProvider](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#languages.registerDocumentFormattingEditProvider)

You must create a new [`DocumentFormattingEditProvider`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#DocumentFormattingEditProvider) and then pass it to `monaco.languages.registerDocumentFormattingEditProvider`. For example:

```
const cssFormatProvider = {
    provideDocumentFormattingEdits(model, options, token) {
        return [{
            text: YourFormatter(model.getValue()) // put formatted text here
            range: model.getFullModelRange()
        }];
    }
};
const languageId = 'css';

monaco.languages.registerDocumentFormattingEditProvider(languageId, cssFormatProvider);
```

Comment: did that.. for some reason the event doesn't fire for me..

Comment: @EliorMalul : I hope this will match your case, please refer: https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/2296. It allowed 'html' and 'json' only. I checked at monaco-editor version 0.33.0. So css is not able to do that.